# How to verify if clicked text is formatted?

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I want to use my own custom buttons instead of default toolbar.  To bold selected text I use something like this:

```
<BoldButton onClick={this.onBoldClick} />

onBoldClick = () => {
    editor.execute('bold');
};
```

And it works fine. But when I click unbolded text I want my button to be gray, but if I click on some bolded text I want button to be green. I have no idea how can I achieve this. I see that in original Bold button there is some piece of code response for it, but I don’t know how can I use it in my  case:

```
view.bind( 'isOn', 'isEnabled' ).to( command, 'value', 'isEnabled' );
this.listenTo( view, 'execute', () => editor.execute( BOLD ) );
```

Any ideas, how can I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CKEditor 5 [commands](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/architecture/core-editor-architecture.html#commands) have observable properties: `value` and `isEnabled`. You can [attach listeners](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/deep-dive/ui/external-ui.html#binding-the-buttons-to-editor-commands) and react when those properties change:

```
const command = editor.commands.get( 'bold' );

command.on( 'change:isEnabled', () => {
    if ( command.isEnabled ) {
        // Make the button enabled.
    } else {
        // Make the button disabled.
    }
} );

command.on( 'change:value', () => {
    if ( command.value ) {
        // Make the button green.
    } else {
        // Make the button gray.
    }
} );
```

Check out the [guide about using the external UI](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/deep-dive/ui/external-ui.html) with CKEditor 5 to learn more.